# python userdata trouble with stalled process

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am having trouble getting a python script using boto3 working. I am attempting to launch this in windows, python 2.7 with boto3, using an instance userdata  script.

I have confirmed that the script is called, and I end up with a log file which indicates the last line that was executed was:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Unfortunately when I view the task monitor, and look at the powershell and python script processes, they are sitting there idle, and the script is not proceeding, and no apparent error has occurred.

Is there any reason why using boto3 in this way is a bad idea?  I am at a loss for figuring out the issue with no error, and an idle process.  I have confirmed that running the same command from the command prompt on the same ec2 instance via RDP does work as expected (meaning the IAM role is OK), so is this somehow related to running with userdata?

I enabled full botocore debugging and my log looks like this:

```
11-28 21:39 root         INFO     startup
11-28 21:39 root         INFO     creating boto3 s3 resource
11-28 21:39 botocore.loaders DEBUG    Loading JSON file: C:\python27\lib\site-packages\boto3-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\boto3\data\s3\2006-03-01\resources-1.json
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: env
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: assume-role
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: config-file
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: ec2-credentials-file
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: boto-config
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: container-role
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials DEBUG    Looking for credentials via: iam-role
11-28 21:39 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO     Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
11-28 21:39 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG    "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21
11-28 21:39 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO     Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
11-28 21:39 botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG    "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/fullAccessToS3_catcfs HTTP/1.1" 200 882
11-28 21:39 botocore.credentials INFO     Found credentials from IAM Role: fullAccessToS3_catcfs
11-28 21:39 botocore.loaders DEBUG    Loading JSON file: C:\python27\lib\site-packages\botocore-1.4.70-py2.7.egg\botocore\data\endpoints.json
```

The code I am running via userdata (again it is stalling on the s3 = boto3.resource('s3')) line

```
 def main():
    """to be run on by each instance as a startup command"""
    import boto3, argparse, sys
    from s3interface import S3Interface
    from manifest import Manifest
    from instancemanager import InstanceManager
    from loghelper import LogHelper
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="AWS Instance bootstrapper" +
                    "Loads manifest which contains data and commands to run on this instance,"+
                    "downloads data from S3, runs commands, and uploads results to S3")

    parser.add_argument("--bucketName", help = "the name of the S3 bucket to work with", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--manifestKey", help = "the key pointing to the manifest file in the s3 bucket", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--instanceId", help = "the id of this instance as defined in the manifest file", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--localWorkingDir", help = "a directory to store working files, it will be created if it does not exist on the instance", required=True)

    try:
        boto3.set_stream_logger(name='botocore')
        args = vars(parser.parse_args())
        bootstrapper = None

        bucketName = args["bucketName"]
        manifestKey = args["manifestKey"]
        instanceId = int(args["instanceId"])
        localWorkingDir = args["localWorkingDir"]

        if not os.path.exists(localWorkingDir):
            os.makedirs(localWorkingDir)
        logPath = os.path.join(localWorkingDir, "log_instance{0}.txt".format(instanceId))
        LogHelper.start_logging(logPath)
        logging.info("startup")
        logging.info("creating boto3 s3 resource")
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        logging.info("creating S3Interface")
        s3interface = S3Interface(s3, bucketName, localWorkingDir)

        localManifestPath = os.path.join(localWorkingDir, "manifest.json")
        logging.info("downloading manifest from S3")
        s3interface.downloadFile(manifestKey, localManifestPath)
        manifest = Manifest(localManifestPath)
        instancemanager = InstanceManager(s3interface, manifest)
        bootstrapper = AWSInstanceBootStrapper(instanceId,
                                               manifest, 
                                               s3interface, 
                                               instancemanager,
                                               logPath)
        bootstrapper.DownloadS3Documents()
        bootstrapper.RunCommands()
        bootstrapper.UploadS3Documents()
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("error in bootstrapper")
        if bootstrapper is not None:
            bootstrapper.UploadLog()
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I wonder whether you have the Region set correctly, since it determines the URL for the endpoint used to send API requests. A frequent error is specifying an availability zone (eg `us-west-2a`) instead of a region (eg `us-west-2`). Do you have a Region defined in a configuration file? Alternative, run `aws configure` and hit Enter a few times to see if a default region has been set.

Comment: It turns out this had absolutely nothing to do with boto3 as far as I can tell.  I was trying to run a python script from user data in a windows server 2012 AMI using EC2Config userdata, and it was stalling during the script for some reason.  I spent endless time trying to search for issues in my script, and didnt see any eplanation for this.  I switched to a windows server 2016 AMI with EC2Launch and my script now works on this AMI.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely a misspelled or incorrect region. I had a region set to `us_east-1` instead of `us-east-1` and I got a `Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254`. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein